# Combinatoric meaning of $\binom{n}{k}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, statistics

$$\binom{n}{k}$$ Means how many ways there are to choose $k$ objects out of $n$ objects (order of picking doesnt matter).

> But does 
>   $\binom{n}{k}$ also mean how many ways there are to arrange $k$ objects out of the $n$ total objects?

Because for example, stars and bars:

$$ + + + | + | + + $$

You would do $\binom{8}{2}$

Thanks!

Comment: Some time ago I try to explain visually this topic [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002944/combinations-10-people-divided-in-to-two-groups-one-of-6-and-one-of-4/1003076#1003076).

Comment: The "fundamental" combinatorial meaning of $\binom{n}{k}$ is as you described. But the binomial coefficient turns up in other places. For example, let us count the number of sequences of $0$'s and $1$'s of length $n$ that have exactly $k$ $1$'s. This problem looks like a "permutations" problem. But  such a sequence is completely determined if we **choose** the $k$ places occupied by $1$'s, so the answer is $\binom{n}{k}$. Your Stars and Bars example is another somewhat more complicated one.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, so $\binom{n}{k}$ does indeed tell how many ways there are to arrange $k$ objects within $n$?

Comment: If the objects are of  **two kinds**, say $0$ and $1$, or H (head) and T, and objects of the same kind are indistinguishable.

Comment: @Amad27: In the example you wrote, you choose 2 places for bars out of 8 places.

Comment: @mathlove, yes but that means I calculated how many arrangements are possible by $\binom{n}{k}$ then right?

Comment: Doesn't "arrange $k$ objects" imply that order IS important?

Comment: @AndréNicolas, what do you mean indistinguishable? For example how many nonegative integer solutions exist to : $a + b + c = 4$ You have $4$ stars and $2$ bars:

$$ x | x | xx$$ For example. 

Then what does $\binom{6}{2}$ mean? The number of arrangements of the two bars out of $6$ objects? If so, is this a general case?

Comment: The number of solutions is $\binom{4+3-1}{4}$, or equivalently $\binom{4+3-1}{3-1}$. The method works in general. There is a good discussion in Wikipedia. I have always thought of it in terms of distributing $4+3$ identical candies   to $3$ kids and then taking a candy away from each, that way I see more clearly what the bars represent.

Answer (score 1):

**Permutations.** A simple example in which it is possible to show all possibilities
may be helpful. Suppose you have three objects A, B, and C.
You wish to select two of the three and arrange them. The possibilities are:

```
    AB  AC
BA      BC
CA  CB
```

In frequently used combinatiorial notation, the number of arrangements is 
$${}_3P_2 = \frac{3!}{(3-2)!} = \frac{3!}{1!} = 3(2) =  6.$$

**Combinations.** If you wish to choose 2 of these three objects without
regard to order, then the actual order is unimportant,
so we choose *alphabetical* order to make our list, ignoring the three
(now redundant) outcomes that are not in alphabetical order:

```
    AB  AC
        BC
```

In frequently used combinatorial notation, the number of ways
to choose the objects without regard to order is
$${}_3C_2 = {3 \choose 2} =\frac{3!}{2!\,(3-2)!} = \frac{3!}{2!\,1!} =3.$$

*Note:* In stars-and-bars problems, you have a number of *positions*
among the stars available to receive the bars. The order in which
the bars are inserted is not relevant, so this becomes a
problem involving binomial coefficients ${positions \choose bars}$.
I am not sure *exactly* what problem you intended to solve by
${8 \choose 2},$ so I hesitate to comment on details of that.

Comment: (+1) good answer. But the bottomline question I had was for $k$ DIFFERENT objects out of $n$ objects does $\binom{n}{k}$ also show how many arrangements are possible of the two bars out of the $n$ total stars and bars.

Comment: "Stars" are indistinguishable. Suggest you open a **new question** asking exactly what you want, giving examples of possibilities, what does and does not count as a different arrangement. For example, whether  |++++++| is possible, whether +++||+++ is possible, etc. (FYI, for "voting," you have to click an arrow, making it turn red.)

Comment: sorry, I pressed the button again. All I am asking is, does $\binom{n}{k}$ give the number of arrangements of $k$ objects out of $n$ total objects?

Comment: Usually 'arrangements' means permutations. As noted above, the notation ${n \choose k}$ is for 'combinations' (unordered subsamples).