# Combinatorics question of understanding the cases where 2 cannot be counted together

Tags: combinatorics

I have a slight confusion about the following question.

From a group of 8 women and 6 men, a committee consisting of 3 men and 3 women is to be formed. How many different committees are possible if
(b) 2 of the women refuse to serve together?

In this case, the answer is given by

$${6 \choose 3}{6 \choose 3}+{2 \choose 1}{6 \choose 2}{6 \choose 3}$$

I understand the 1st part where we are accounting for all the women except for the 2 that refuses to work together. However, I am a bit confused about the terms of the 2nd part. I can see that we can re-arrange and choose 1 women and vice versa so we have ${2 \choose 1}$ and that ${6 \choose 3}$ which is the number of men that can be picked. I also understand that because we are accounting for the case where we choose one of the women refusing to work with the other, we only pick the remaining 2 spots remaining. However, Im a bit confused as to why the numerator is $6!$. I can see why it is $6!$ but why so in the second case as well ?

Thanks

Comment: There are 6 women other than those two, out of which we pick 2.

Comment: I'm confused where do you see this $6!$ coming up in the numerator?  I don't see what $6!$ you're referring to.

Comment: Thats from the ${6 \choose 2} = \frac{6!}{2!4!}$

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002944/combinations-10-people-divided-in-to-two-groups-one-of-6-and-one-of-4/1003076#1003076) can be useful for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case 1: In this case you don't have the two women who don't like to be together . So now you have $6$ women and you want to chose $3$ out of them. Similarly chose $3$ men out of the $6$ men. That is $$\binom{6}{3}\binom{6}{3}$$

Case 2: In this case you have one of the women out of the two who don not want to be together. So to chose that you have $\binom{2}{1}$ different ways of doing it. Now since you have already chosen one women you have $2$ more places to fill in with women in the committee. This can be done in $\binom{6}{2}$ different ways. Why $6$? Because you have chosen one women out the two who do not want to be together. Now you cannot bring one of the women's in the picture again. Now similarly as the first case count the men . That is $\binom{6}{3}$. Therefore the total number of ways in which you can do this is :$${6 \choose 3}{6 \choose 3}+{2 \choose 1}{6 \choose 2}{6 \choose 3}$$ That is adding the two cases.